# How to get Exact Age basing on the Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sample Data :

```
DECLARE @T Table (ID INT,Name VARCHAR(10),DOB DATE)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (1,'Mohan','1937-12-30')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (2,'Raj','1937-12-25')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (5,'Manny','1937-01-30')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (3,'kamal','1938-12-12')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (4,'Raj','1937-05-12')
```

My Query :

```
Select 
cast((DATEDIFF(m, DOB, GETDATE())/12) as varchar) + ' Y & ' + 
       cast((DATEDIFF(m, DOB, GETDATE())%12) as varchar) + ' M & ' +
       cast((DATEDIFF(D, DOB, GETDATE())%12) as varchar) + ' d'   as Age from @T
```

This will give result in Years, months and Days . 
But My question how to get data only who are reaching 79 years of age in Coming 45 days . 
I'm struck can you please suggest me

Comment: is the 79years and 45days static or will they change?

Comment: Given my answer below, check once

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean with "exact age"?

Comment: those who are reaching 79 age with in 45 days@LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People who are reaching 79 years of age in the next 45 days:

```
SELECT * from @T where
DOB > DATEADD(year,-79,GETDATE()) and
DOB < DATEADD(year,-79,DATEADD(day,45,GETDATE()))
```

(Adjust for `<` vs `<=` and possible employ additional `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF`s if you wish to round `GETDATE()` down to midnight, to suit your exact requirements)

Comment: Careful with leap years!

Comment: @mendosi - have you got a specific example DOB/run date that you think that leap years will make problematic here?

Comment: No, you are correct. The DATEADD() function handles leap years. Some of the other ones don't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is not producing any result

Comment: @mohan111 - well, if we take your sample data, none of them *are* due to turn 79 in the next 45 days. You'll notice that the results you're producing with your query don't produce a result consistent with what someone would actually say. E.g., today (2016-11-08), your query reports that Mohan is 78 Y, 11 M and 3 days. But would someone born on 30th december 1937 really report their age as that? Wouldn't they report it as 78 Y, **10** M and 9/10 days? Similarly Raj isn't within 45 days (yet) of turning 79.

Comment: yeah I agree with that  above result set will give the exact result of people who are reaching 79 with in 45 days I have modified and checked it is working but how can we check the data of this week .For example today is Tuesday but I need to look from Monday to Sunday @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Select 
       cast((DATEDIFF(m, DOB, GETDATE())/12) as varchar) + ' Y & ' + 
       cast((DATEDIFF(m, DOB, GETDATE())%12) as varchar) + ' M & ' +
       cast((DATEDIFF(D, DOB, GETDATE())%12) as varchar) + ' d' 
from @T
WHERE DATEDIFF(m, DOB, GETDATE())/12 < 79 -- we need only people how are not already 79 years old
    AND DATEDIFF(m, DATEADD(DAY,-45, DOB), GETDATE())/12 >= 79 -- we are making the DOB 45 days samller
```

Comment: this is giving exact result . But how can I check the data who are nearing the 79 years with in the 45 days for this week . For example today is Tuesday but I need to look from Monday to Sunday

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from @T 
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),DATEADD(yy,79,dob))<45
AND 
DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),DATEADD(yy,79,dob))>0
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
...
WHERE  (DATEDIFF(m, DOB, GETDATE())/12) = 78 AND 
       (DATEDIFF(m, DOB, GETDATE())%12) = 11 AND  
       (DATEDIFF(D, DOB, GETDATE())%12) < 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :
    ;

```
WITH _CTE(_Id,_ConDate ,_Month , _Date ,Name , DOB,_DOBMonth , _DOBDate) AS
(SELECT ID , DATEADD(DAY,45,GETDATE()),DATEPART(M,DATEADD(DAY,45,GETDATE())),
DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(DAY,45,GETDATE())),Name,DOB,DATEPART(MONTH,DOB),DATEPART(DAY,DOB)FROM @T WHERE (DATEDIFF(m, DOB, GETDATE())/12) = 78 )SELECT _Id Id,Name , DOB FROM _CTE WHERE _Month = _DOBMonth AND _Date = _DOBDate
```